# Sharing an ArrayList Between Activities

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I am having problems storing a `List` in an `Application` class across activities.

In my Splash screen, I am loading data into a `List` from a `MySQL` database.

The `List` is in a class called `Rateit` that `extends Application`.  I do this in it as a class variable:

```
public static List<String> masterCats;
```

In the Splash Screen Activity/Class, I do this:

in `onCreate`:

```
Rateit.masterCats = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Inside my AsyncTask loop where loading data I do this:

```
Rateit.masterCats.add(cat);
```

`cat` being the list item that comes from the database.  I have `Log.d` the data (`cat`) as well as the ListPosition to check if it is being added to the `List` and it is.

However, I need to grab that same info in the next `Activity` and put it into an `adapter`.  It comes back with 0 length.

I simply do this:  `adapter = new MasterCatAdapter(getActivity(), Rateit.masterCats, tf);`

How come the list doesn't maintain data across activies?  Is this because its `static`? something else?

(Note:  I will add getter and setter methods here soon!)

Comment: Don't mess with static variables.Stay with persistent storage. Even passing through intents will work if your ArrayList is small.

Comment: I hope you dont mean SQLite?  Or is SharedPreferences a better option?

Comment: According to this doc, Android behaves itself correctly when static variables are used:http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html 
Could it be that something else is clearing your static variable at some point?

Comment: Yes it was. A typo caused index out of bounds error, then adapter was never set.   Poor checking my part.   I'm still planning on using static variables.   I just realized I need to repopulate  them if they ArrayList is empty after app has been in background for a while.  The point of this is to minimize databases calls.

Comment: @A--C I see exactly why static variables is  amess.  MY ListViews randomly have no data whenever the variable value clears.  I don't know if its garbage collected or what.. but that is not a good way.

Comment: @KickingLettuce As you saw, they can introduce bugs and uncertainty of state. Persistent storage is the safest option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @A--C mentioned in his comment, avoid the model you have now with the static variable. Instead, I would do something like this:

```
private void yourMethodWhereYouGetYourData(){
    //get your data
    ArrayList<String> masterCats = new ArrayList<String>();
    masterCats.add(cat);

   //Assuming you're doing this synchronously, once you've gotten your data just do:
   Intent i = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
   i.putStringArrayListExtra("MasterCats", masterCats);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

Then, in your new `Activity`'s `onCreate()` or wherever, just access the list by doing:

```
getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("MasterCats");
```

@KickingLettuce also mentioned in the comments about keeping this accessible if the user navigates away from the `Activity`. So, in whichever `Activity` you want to save the ArrayList, just convert it to a comma-separated String and save it in SharedPreferences like so:

```
private void saveCats(){
    //get your ArrayList from wherever (either as a global variable or pass it into the
    //method.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < masterCats.size(); i++){
        if(i == masterCats.size() - 1)
            sb.append(masterCats.get(i));
        else
            sb.append(masterCats.get(i)+",");
    }

    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    prefsEditor.putString("MasterCats", sb.toString()).commit();

    //Note: in API 11 and beyond you can store a Set of Strings in SharedPreferences, so
    //if you are only targeting API 11+ you could do:
    Set<String> masterCatsSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>(); //<--using LinkedHashSet to preserve order
    masterCatsSet.addAll(masterCats);
    prefsEditor.putStringSet("MasterCats",masterCatsSet).commit();
}
```

Then access this SharedPreference in your `onCreate` or something if you wish to persist the list across the `Activity` lifecycle.

Comment: I like this, but I need to maintain this info while the app is active (in case the user comes back to this activity).  I don't beleive this does that?

Comment: If you store it as a global variable in the Activity, assuming the Activity isn't destroyed, it will still be accessible. If the Activity does become destroyed, there are a number of persistent storage options as well. I will update with how I would handle it to persist across the activity lifecycle.

Comment: I tried it my way and failed.  I see why using static variables is a mess.  Completely unreliable.   I have seen your way is correct and will mark it right since it's obvious this is the best way.

Comment: Ah, just saw that this requires API 11 and I am targeting 10.  Hopefully soon I can drop 10, but not sure its possible yet...

Answer (score 1):

saving the List in a Application extended class is good idea you can achieve it by following

Declare List as follows in your App class like

```
public static List<String> masterCats;
```

and declare setter and getter methods for above variable

```
public List getMasterCatsList()
 {
    return masteCats;
 }

public Void setMasterCatsList(List list)
 {
    masteCats=list;
 }
```

get the application object as follows in your Loader class as follows

Application application = (YOurClassName That Extends Application class) getApplication();

and set the list as follows

```
  application.setMasterCatsList(List list);
```

now you can access this list from any activity as follows

```
  Application application = (YOurClassName That Extends Application class) getApplication();

 List l = application.getMasterCatsList();
```

hope it will be helpful to you